# Conditional counting within category

Tags: r, dplyr

Within a set of categories, I'm trying to count how many of the value in a real data set are within a set of simulated values, and I can't think of how to write the r code for it though I've been messing around with dplyr some.

```
     Example: 

     category <-  c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
     dist <- c(50,20,50,50,70,70,50,50,50,50,70,70)
     type <- c("real", "sim", "sim","sim", "real", "sim", 
     "sim","sim","real", "sim", "sim","sim")

    df <- data.frame(category,dist,type)
    df


     category dist type
         1   50 real
         1   20  sim
         1   50  sim
         1   50  sim
         2   70 real
         2   70  sim
         2   50  sim
         2   50  sim
         3   50 real
         3   50  sim
         3   70  sim
         3   70  sim




What I want:

category count 
        1   2 
        2   1  
        3   1
```

Comment: The only way I can get your expected output is this: `df %>% group_by(category) %>% summarise(count = sum(dist[type == 'real'] == dist) - 1)` but I feel this is not the logic you need

Comment: Can you check the input and thee expected.  Is there a typo in the 'count'

Comment: Maybe you mean  "how many of the values marked as *simulated* are in the set of *real* values"? (In the text of the question, "simulated" and "real" are reversed vs the question as stated in this comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers above didn't do it for me, but that's probably my fault with wording. In case anyone else has the same problem, I found that the below solution worked for me.

```
    #getting values of a row

  sim <- subset(both, Type == "sim")
  snake <- subset(both, Type == "real")

  snake <- snake %>% slice(rep(1:n(), 1000)) ##1000 was the number of total simulated 
 animals I had

  count <- ifelse(snake$dist >= sim$dist, 1, ifelse(snake$dist < sim$dist,0,NA))
  count <- as.data.frame(count)
  count <- cbind(count, sim$category)
  colnames(count) <- c("binary", "category")
  head(count)

  totalB <- aggregate(binary~category, count, FUN = sum)
  names(totalB)[2] <- 'total'
  head(totalB)
```

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to `group_by` 'category', and `summarise` by checking the 'dist' values of 'type' 'sim' less than those of the 'real' 'type'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(category) %>% 
   summarise(count = sum(unique(dist[type == 'sim']) <= dist[type == 'real'][1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach with `reshape2`,

```
library(reshape2)

df2 <- as.data.frame(table(df))

my_cast <- dcast(df2,type~ category+dist,value.var="Freq")

col = apply(my_cast, 2, function(col) all(col !=0 ))

as.data.frame(t(my_cast[,col][2,]))


   # type sim
   # 1_50   2
   # 2_70   1
   # 3_50   1
```